# JQuery AutoComplete Combobox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox

I have been trying to get my head around autocomplete in a short time and am just banging my head against the wall trying to make it work.  I've tried numerous examples and none make sense enough for me to use.

I have created an example that I hope explains what I am trying to do.  This is an MVC 3 application

I am using the autocomplete code from the jquery site at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox and I have this linked into the header of my _Layout.cshtml file along with all other required js and css files.

The Div which is in my view on Home/Index.cshtml and button with which to perform an action with.

```
<div id="SearchDiv"></div>
<button id="SearchBtn" type="button" style="float: right">Search</button>
```

The view includes the js file where I create the SELECT element and also define the button click.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/combobox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The JS file contents are as follows.

```
        var theader = '<table class="tbl">\n';
        var tbody = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        tbody += '<tr>';
    tbody += '<td><select class="SelectionControls"/><option value="0"></option>';
    tbody += '<option value="1">This is a test</option>';
    tbody += '<option value="2">This is a test 1</option>';
    tbody += '<option value="3">This is a test 2</option>';
    tbody += '<option value="4">This is a test 3</option>';
    tbody += '<option value="5">This is a test 4</option>';
    tbody += '<select></td>';

    if (i % 2 != 0)
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
}
var tfooter = '</table>';
document.getElementById('SearchDiv').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;

$(".SelectionControls").combobox();

$("#SearchBtn").click(function () {
    var readtheselectedvalue= $(".SelectionControls")[0].val();
});
```

Nothing happens when I run the code apart from it putting comboboxes onto the screen in a table but they are all empty.  I need the comboboxes to be populated with the textural values above so the selected text is shown in the combobox textfield when an item is selected but when I read the val() I need it to return the value associated with that selection 0 - 5.

I need to be able to read the value 0-5 in javascript as I have further processing I need to do with the value once the Search button is pressed.

If anyone could please tell me how I accomplish this I would be very grateful as I've been struggling with this for ages.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, are you going to be searching on a model with this combobox? Will the autocomplete be searching a collection of select objects populated by your controller, or will it be a static list hard-coded in your JS file? You should have a look at Select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) and Chosen (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), I've used both in ASP MVC apps and they're great

Comment: The combobox is displaying a json result, thats why I have created the combobox in javascript.  The combobox is part of an external jqgrid filtering system I am writing.  I needed the create the combobox dynamically as there can be several, all user configurable, so I couldn't simply drop them into HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that since you are creating your select list in the same JavaScript function that you are creating your combobox, the select list isn't yet in the document and therefore the combobox plugin can't find it to build your autocomplete list.  You could try a couple things:

1. Just make your select list in the HTML of your view instead of building it with JavaScript.  I don't really see any reason why you need to do it with JavaScript.  Then, put your call to .combobox() inside of document.ready() so that it is only called after the document is fully loaded.

   ```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        (".SelectionControls").combobox();
    });
   ```
2. If you must build it JS try putting your call to .combobox inside of a setTimeout.  This may give the page enough time to update before calling the .combox function that it will be there when .combobox is looking for it.

   ```
    setTimeout(function(){$(".SelectionControls").combobox()}, 0);
   ```

Also, after also struggling with autocomplete comboboxes, I finally just wrote my own plugin that does everything I need.  It's at https://github.com/tmooney3979/jquery.ui.combify if you want to try it out.

Comment: I've gotten this working, don't ask me how as I couldn't tell you.  It must just of been something I had mistyped or something.  Anyway.  I have now disabled part of the removeIfInvalid method that removes the invalid text from the input box of the combobox.  How would I read this text as its just free text and not a selection from within the combobox?  I can't seem to gain access to it.

Answer (score 8):

Just a hint after struggling with so many autocompletion scripts myself.

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is the best autocomplete plugin ever.

Comment: I've gotten this to work now.  Would you know how I read the freetext the user can input into the text box of the combobox as I have disabled the part of the autocomplete js that removes this as I want to retain it and read it.